# how to insert many records excluding some

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I want to create a table with a subset of records from a master table.
for example, i have:

```
id  name   code
1   peter  73
2   carl   84
3   jack   73
```

I want to store peter and carl but not jack because has same peter's code.
I need hight performance because i have 20M records.

I try this:

```
SELECT id, name, DISTINCT(code) INTO new_tab
FROM old_tab 
WHERE (conditions)
```

but don't work.

Comment: Your first problem is defining your tie-breaker. When confronted with Peter and Jack, why choose Peter over Jack? Are you using the lowest id? Once I know the tie-breaker. I can write the query.

Comment: I want the record with min id. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to pick the row with the maximum `id` per `code`, then this should do it:

```
insert into new_tab (id, name, code) 
(SELECT id, name, code 
 FROM 
 (
   SELECT id, name, code, rank() as rnk OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY id DESC) 
   FROM old_tab WHERE rnk = 1
 )
)
```

and for the minimum `id` per code, just change the sort order in the rank from DESC to ASC:

```
insert into new_tab (id, name, code) 
(SELECT id, name, code 
 FROM 
 (
   SELECT id, name, code, rank() as rnk OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY id ASC) 
   FROM old_tab WHERE rnk = 1
 )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a derived table, you can find the minID for each code, then join back to that in the outer to get the rest of the columns for that ID from oldTab.

```
select id,name,code
insert into newTabFROM
from old_tab t inner join
    (SELECT min(id) as minId, code
    from old_tab group by code) x
on t.id = x.minId
WHERE (conditions)
```

Comment: If that is supposed to create a new table, it should be `into newTab` (get rid of the `insert`). If that should insert into an existing table, the `insert into` needs to be the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    ID INT, 
    Name VARCHAR(50), 
    Code INT
)

INSERT #Temp VALUES (1, 'Peter', 73)
INSERT #Temp VALUES (2, 'Carl', 84)
INSERT #Temp VALUES (3, 'Jack', 73)

SELECT t2.ID, t2.Name, t2.Code
FROM #Temp t2
    JOIN (
        SELECT t.Code, MIN(t.ID) ID
        FROM #temp t
            JOIN (
                SELECT DISTINCT Code 
                FROM #Temp
                ) d
                ON t.Code = d.Code
        GROUP BY t.Code
            ) b
    ON t2.ID = b.ID
```